# Function with return type defined by a type member of its argument

Tags: scala

**Updated my question per feedback from commenters (Miles and m-z):**

I'm finding duplicate "values" by either Name or Age.

```
sealed trait DuplicateResult 
case class DuplicatesByName(name: String, people: Set[String]) extends DuplicateResult
case class DuplicatesByAge(age: Int, people: Set[String]) extends DuplicateResult
```

And the return type must be different depending on Name or Age:

```
sealed trait QueryByDuplicate {
  type DuplicateResultType
}

case class Name(name: String) extends QueryByDuplicate {
  override type DuplicateResultType = DuplicatesByName
}

case class Age(age: Int) extends QueryByDuplicate {
  override type DuplicateResultType = DuplicatesByAge
}
```

Then, I define a function that compiles and runs:

```
def findDupes(x: QueryByDuplicate): DuplicateResult = x match {
  case Name(n) => DuplicatesByName(n, Set("1", "2"))
  case Age(a)  => DuplicatesByAge(a, Set("42"))
}

scala> findDupes(Name("kevin"))
res0: DuplicateResult = DuplicatesByName(kevin,Set(1, 2))

scala> findDupes(Age(77))
res1: DuplicateResult = DuplicatesByAge(77,Set(42))
```

However, the `type DuplicateResultType` seems weak, since I could put any type there.

Please criticize and improve my implementation.

Comment: What role is `FooString` intended to play here?

Comment: For any `Foo`, `Foo#A` isn't necessarily a `String`, so what do you want to happen?

Comment: Did you intend to write `foo match` instead of `f match`?

Comment: Thanks, Miles and m-z, for the probing questions. I updated my question if you could please take a look.

Comment: Tip: if you pasted plain Scala code instead of repl outputs in your question, it would be both easier to read, and easier to copy-paste and play with locally.

Comment: Agree with @Mifeet, so much vertical space is wasted by superfluous "defined class ...", not to mention all the REPL noise.

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1:* The result type information is lost in your version because the caller cannot influence the fixed result type of `findDupes`. You can use generics so that the caller regains this control:

```
sealed trait QueryByDuplicate[T <: DuplicateResult]
case class Name(name: String) extends QueryByDuplicate[DuplicatesByName]
case class Age(age: Int) extends QueryByDuplicate[DuplicatesByAge]

def findDupes[T <: DuplicateResult](x: QueryByDuplicate[T]): T = x match {
  case Name(n) => DuplicatesByName(n, Set("1", "2"))
  case Age(a) => DuplicatesByAge(a, Set("42"))
}
val dupes: DuplicatesByName = findDupes(Name("kevin"))
```

---

*Option 2:* Since you asked for criticism too, I don't think the way you designed things is a good practice. Having several classes defining your queries, and a list of implementations for each class at a different place is duplicity hard to maintain. You could just use good old polymorphism:

```
  sealed trait QueryByDuplicate[T <: DuplicateResult] {
    def findDupes: T
  }
  class Name(name: String) extends QueryByDuplicate[DuplicatesByName] {
    override def findDupes: DuplicatesByName = DuplicatesByName(name, Set("1", "2"))
  }
  class Age(age: Int) extends QueryByDuplicate[DuplicatesByAge] {
    override def findDupes: DuplicatesByAge = DuplicatesByAge(age, Set("42"))
  }
  val dupes: DuplicatesByName = new Name("kevin").findDupes
```

This is how you would probably do it in Java. Sometimes it's better to stick to good old ways even when we have new toys.

---

*Option 3:*  Talking about `instanceOf`, this also works:

```
  sealed trait QueryByDuplicate {
    type DuplicateResultType
  }
  case class Name(name: String) extends QueryByDuplicate {
    override type DuplicateResultType = DuplicatesByName
  }

  case class Age(age: Int) extends QueryByDuplicate {
    override type DuplicateResultType = DuplicatesByAge
  }

  def findDupes(x: QueryByDuplicate): x.DuplicateResultType = x match {
    case Name(n) => DuplicatesByName(n, Set("1", "2")).asInstanceOf[x.DuplicateResultType]
    case Age(a) => DuplicatesByAge(a, Set("42")).asInstanceOf[x.DuplicateResultType]
  }
  val dupes: DuplicatesByName = findDupes(Name("kevin"))
```

`findDupes()` will have a return type of `Object` in the bytecode, but Scala is smart enough to infer the correct type, apparently.

Comment: Surely we can do better than resorting to `.asInstanceOf[T]`, no?

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer. It's just that my IntelliJ Idea yells at me without it for some reason.